# Executing a graph of scripts

Tags: sql, language-agnostic, graph-theory

I have some (SQL) scripts. Most of them have some requirements: other scripts that should be run before.

You can imagine the merged dependency trees as a *directed graph*. I would like to be able to "invalidate" a certain node in the graph, which would result in a composite script which contains everything (in the right order) that should be re-run to reach the ready state.

I think of something like the Debian start-up process... with a twist.

**Edit:** If anyone needs an explicit question startting with **W** and ending with a question mark, the closest I can give:
*How can I achieve the behavior described above.*

**Edit2:** The ideal solution would be something that scans files matching a pattern, and reading dependency info from the first (comment) line.

Comment: To me your "A invalidates B" concept seems to be the inverse ("dual" ?) of make's "B depends on A". If you have the dependancy graph in one form it can be transformed into the other.

Answer (score 4):

You could use make. Create a naming convention for stampfiles (maybe use the logfiles from the scripts) The Makefile can be generated by a script.
Example:

```
stamp1: stamp2 stamp3 script1.sql
     sql <script1.sql > $@

stamp2: stamp3 stamp5 script2.sql
     sql <script2.sql > $@

...
```

EDIT:
A Makefile is a Directed Acyclic Graph. In the above fragment, stamp1 "depends on" {stamp2,stamp3,script3.sql}: if any of these change, the line below it (sql <>) will be executed. So if script1 should always be run after script2, the above fragment would apply.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can't really see how deleting `stamp3` will automatically cause (for example) `stamp2` to run. Deleting an individual node here would not cause all the dependencies to be run again.

Comment: I did not realize make will automatically "refresh" every dependency on change. - A concrete example: on kernel compiling when I cange a `.c` file almost every time I have to do `make clean` too. But I'm definitely checking out *make*.

Comment: Well, stamp3 should have a production rule as well (which produces stamp3 and finally recreate stamp2 and stamp1. But I do agree that in your casus the causality seems to be reversed wrt "make".

Comment: The "make clean" should normally not be needed. It violates the purpose of make. Make clean **should** only be needed if the topology (of the DAG) changes.

Answer (score 2):

[sorry, earlier answer was not general enough.  now fixed]

you need a topological sort of your graph.  see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting which says:

> The canonical application of topological sorting (topological order)
>   is in scheduling a sequence of jobs or tasks

that defines both your initial build order and how you can restart from any intermediate, invalidated, point (just locate that point in the sorted list and start from there).

you can also sort the subgraph reachable from an invalidated point, which will give you less points in some cases (you avoid rebuilding points on the original sort that could have been built "in parallel" with the invalid node, and their children) (to find the subgraph from a point just do a breadth first search from there).

ps since the order must be the same you can simply filter the global order for points that are below your invalidated point.  in other words, you don't need to actually do the resort, just start from the invalidated point on your global list and skip nodes that are not in the subgraph below your bad point.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also recommend any tool which resolves this for me? `tsort` seems nice but It won't handle the *rebuilding* scenario, when one node falls out (so no full rebuild required).

Comment: In the example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsort_(Unix)#Examples deleting 11 will also cause 8 to rebuild although there was no such dependency. I think this logic only works for full builds.

Comment: we seem to have crossed wires.  i expanded on that above, perhaps while you were posting.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use an approach that "bubbles" the order by finding errors?  I've done this a number of times manually and have thought about writing a program to automate it:

Something like, given list of scripts L:

1. Start Transaction
2. Set i=1
3. Run L[i]
4. If Error Move L[i] to end of L, Rollback, Goto 1
5. Else i=i+1, Goto 3